# Как отключить QRadioButton при повторном нажатий?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyside2, qradiobutton

Мне нужно при повторном нажатии на `QRadioButton` кнопка отключалась

Мой код

```
def offRadioButton(self):
    check_1 = self.sender().isChecked()
    if check_1 == True:
        print('check')
        self.sender().setAutoExclusive(True)   #Unchecked/Checked
        self.sender().setChecked(False)    #Unchecked/Checked
        self.sender().setAutoExclusive(False)  #Unchecked/Checked
    else:
        print('uncheked')
```

Я смог отключить кнопку, но проблема в том, что после повторного нажатия кнопка превращается в `Checkbox` и обратно становится радио не хочет/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я пробовал еще использовать `.setExclusive()`, но команда вызывает ошибку

> AttributeError: 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QRadioButton' object has no attribute 'setExclusive'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

я не уверен, что правильно вас понял, но попробуйте `отключалась QRadioButton при повторном нажатии` так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QRadioButton, QHBoxLayout, QButtonGroup, 
    QApplication, QWidget)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.main_layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        attrs            = ['a', 'b', 'c']
        self.buttonGroup = ['a', 'b', 'c']

        for i, attr in enumerate(attrs):
            self.buttonGroup[i] = QButtonGroup(exclusive=False)
            rb = QRadioButton('{}_rb'.format(attr))
            self.buttonGroup[i].addButton(rb)
            self.main_layout.addWidget(rb) 
            self.buttonGroup[i].buttonClicked.connect(self.check_button)

    def check_button(self, radioButton):
        print("\nнажата кнопка -> `{} - {}`".format(radioButton.text(), radioButton.isChecked()))

        print('состояние всех кнопок:') #, self.buttonGroup)
        for i, rb in enumerate(self.buttonGroup):
            print(rb.buttons()[0].text(), rb.buttons()[0].isChecked())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    a_window = Window()
    a_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> Мне нужно чтобы радио работало как обычно, но если я нажимаю на уже активное радио, то кнопка становилась False. Код, который вы дали ничем не отличается от обычного checkbox. **Нельзя что бы одновременно было нажито несколько радио.**

---

**Из документации:**

> В исключительной группе пользователь не может снять отмеченную кнопку, нажав на нее; 
>   вместо этого нужно нажать другую кнопку в группе, 
>   чтобы установить новую отмеченную кнопку для этой группы.

---

Тогда пойдем другим путем. 
Добавим еще одну кнопку `rb3`, 
которую нигде не показываем, но используем ее, когда нам надо.

Также нам нужен словарь,
в котором будем фиксировать состояние кнопок до нажатия на них.

Пробуйте.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QRadioButton, QHBoxLayout, QButtonGroup, 
    QApplication, QWidget)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self._dictRB = {                                            # +++
            'rb0': False,
            'rb1': False,
            'rb2': False,
            'rb3': False,
        }

        self.main_layout = QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.buttonGroup = QButtonGroup()
        self.attr_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.attr_layout)

        self.rb0 = QRadioButton('rb0')
        self.attr_layout.addWidget(self.rb0)
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.rb0)

        self.rb1 = QRadioButton('rb1')
        self.attr_layout.addWidget(self.rb1)
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.rb1)               

        self.rb2 = QRadioButton('rb2')
        self.attr_layout.addWidget(self.rb2)
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.rb2) 

        self.rb3 = QRadioButton('rb3')                               # +++
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.rb3)                         # +++

        self.buttonGroup.buttonClicked.connect(self.check_button)

    def check_button(self, radioButton):
        if self._dictRB[radioButton.text()]:
            self._dictRB[radioButton.text()] = False
            self._dictRB['rb3'] = True
            self.rb3.setChecked(True)                                 # !!!
        else:
            for b in self._dictRB:
                self._dictRB[b] = False
            self._dictRB[radioButton.text()] = True

        print("Нажата кнопка -> `{} - {}`".format(radioButton.text(), radioButton.isChecked()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы радио работало как обычно но если я нажимаю на уже активное радио то кнопка становилась False. код который вы дали ничем не отличается от обычного checkbox. нельзя что бы одновременно было нажито несколько радио

Comment: @orlatym я добавил обновление в свой ответ.